# PDO statement fails with error "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format"

Tags: php, pdo

I have this piece of code for execute a prepared PDO statement:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO territories(territory_id,`name`,`inactive`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES(?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())';
$stmt = $pdoPdone->prepare($sql);
$params = [$territoryId, $territoryName, $inactive];

var_export($params);

$stmt->execute($params);
```

The output of `var_export($params)` is as show below:

```
array (
  0 => '04T80000000TQw1EAG',
  1 => 'SA_106SN03',
  2 => false,
)
```

But when I try to execute the code I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'inactive' at row 1' in /var/sync/sync_bi/sync.php:260
Stack trace:
#0 /var/sync/sync_bi/sync.php(260): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/sync/sync_bi/sync.php on line 260
```

Where line 260 is `$stmt->execute($params)`, so what is wrong? Why PHP or PDO gets confused with value of inactive column?

Comment: The error in the body of your question does not match the error in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array (
  0 => '04T80000000TQw1EAG',
  1 => 'SA_106SN03',
  2 => false, // this should be an integer and not a boolean
)
```

Use `0/1` instead of `false/true`

Answer (score 1):

`inactive` is a boolean rather than an integer. Mysql stores boolean values as a tiny int of 1 or 0, so try setting `inactive` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Replace NOW() with DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')